# Effect of sample size and f(x) on bias and variance components of the error

Tags: regression, error, bias-variance-tradeoff

I was wondering how sample size and the underlying function (linear, logistic, loglinear etc.) affect the bias and variance component of the error.

Is it correct to say that for a perfectly linear set of data, fitting linear regression to this data will give 0 bias? And the variance will decrease as your sample size increases?

Comment: I'm unclear on many parts of your question. By "underlying function," do you mean the true form of the relationship between some specific IV and the DV? By "error," do you mean the residuals of the model, or the estimated standard errors of the coefficients? By "variance component of the error," I assume you mean the variance of the model residuals but I'm not positive. By "perfectly linear set of data," do you mean data in which one or more linear predictors perfectly predicts the DV?